# How to intercept proxy authentication dialog from Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When the proxy requires authentication (a PAC script is used), the user has to enter username and password. Is there any way to replace that dialog with my own script, and then give the browser the data it needs? (username/password pair)

Comment: I haven't extended Chrome, but logically it mustn't be possible since if it was evil scripts could steal usernames and passwords and make improper use of them.

Comment: Well, what I know for sure is that this can be done in Firefox. Basically, I don't even need to show another dialog, as the user/pass pair will be already stored using localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the experimental API WebRequest:[WebRequest#event-onAuthRequired](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webRequest.html#event-onAuthRequired)

But you'll can't put the extension in the Chrome store.

Comment: I wasn't planning to send the extension to the Chrome store. :D